# How to get the value of a particular column from dataframe based on matching data from another field?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which I have imported into pandas DataFrame. The file is as follows:

```
Col1     Col2     Col3     Col4
AB       12       AB12     1,11,12,45
CD       34       CD34     4,6,98,78,12
EF       56       EF56     9,41,52,63,47
```

So, I have created Col3 with the code:

```
df['Col3'] = df['Col1'].str.cat(df['Col2'],sep='')
```

Now, I have a list of values

```
values_list = [['AB','12'],['CD','34'],['EF','56']]
```

So, I want to match the values of the list to the dataframe values and consequently import the values from 'Col4'. I am trying to do this in the following way

```
def extract_values(key):
col4_value = df['Col4'].np.where(df['Col3']==key)
return col4_value

for entry in values_list:
key = ''.join(entry)
extract_values(key)
```

However, this is not working. Any suggestions regarding how to tackle this?
The output expected is:

```
1,11,12,45
4,6,98,78,12
9,41,52,63,47
```

Comment: Please add to the question a sample of the output expected.

Comment: Yes I have added the sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how exactally the values are stored in `Col4`, so I treated them as if they are a string of numbers and commas. You can do:

```
output_values = [list(df[(df['Col1'] == item[0]) & (df['Col2'].astype(str) == item[1])]['Col4']) for item in values_list] #Get the values from the corresponding Col4 where it fits Col1 and Col2
output_values = [list(eval(item[0])) for item in output_values] #Transform the string to a list of values
```

Output:

```
[[1, 11, 12, 45], [4, 6, 98, 78, 12], [9, 41, 52, 63, 47]]
```